# Proving that the sum of a sequence of lower semicontinuous functions is lower semicontinuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble showing that if $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of lower semicontinuous functions  defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and are non-negative, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ is also lower semicontinuous.

I have a counterexample that works to show why this does not hold for upper semicontinuous functions and I can see why I can't modify it to work for lower semicontinuous ones. I also have shown that the above statement holds for exactly two functions, but can't see how to generalize it. (Another source I consulted simply said that it "trivially follows" from the two-function case, which I found rather unhelpful.)

Any insight/help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

(This is a part of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis Chapter 2 Problem 2.)

Comment: The counterexample for upper semicontinuous functions is, if we let ${r_n}$ be an enumeration of the rationals, then we can define $f_n$ by letting $f_n(x)=1$ if $x=r_n$ and zero otherwise. Each is upper semicontinuous since the preimage of any open ray is either empty, all of $\mathbb{R}$, or the line minus a point, all of which are open. Then the infinite sum becomes the characteristic/indicator function on the rationals, but this is not upper semicontinuous since the preimage of $(-\infty,0.5)$ is the irrationals, which is not open.

Comment: As for why it "trivially" follows from the two function case, notice that the supremum of a family of lower semicontinuous functions is again lower semicontinuous. This is easy to see from the definition of lower semicontinuity using $\liminf$. Then your sum is the supremum of the partial sums.

Answer (score 5):

Let $u \in \mathbb{R}_+$. We want to show that $U = \left\{ x : \sum_{n \geq 1} f_n(x) > u \right\}$ is open.

If $x \in U$, then $\sum_{n \geq 1} f_n(x) = \sup_{N \geq 1} \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x) > u$, so there is some $N_x \geq 1$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{N_x} f_n(x) > u$. Hence $x \in U_{N_x} \subset U$, where the subset $U_{N_x} := \left\{ y : \sum_{n = 1}^{N_x} f_n(y) > u \right\}$ is open (a finite sum of lower semicontinuous maps being lower semicontinuous).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\inf(f(x)+g(x))\geq \inf(f(x))+\inf(g(x))$ for nonnegative functions $f,g$.